# Azure DevOps - Auto-redeploy trigger when release fails at certain stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to rollback to previous successful deployment in case of any stage fails in a release/deployment. For that I am trying to use "Auto-redeploy trigger" under "Post-deployment conditions" in a release definition in Azure DevOps.

[image: Post-deployment condition]

However, every time I have a failed deployment no redeployment is triggered. Am I missing any other/additional configuration ? Or how can i achieve this in any other simple/feasible way ?

Here is the release definition history. (I am sure that branch for all definitions is same.) All releases are trigger via CICD.

[image: Release definition history]

Comment: The auto re-deploy is for stage not for a release. do you want if "Upload Artifacts.." stage will fail so the last "Upload artifact..." stage successful release will be triggers again?

Comment: Yes that's what i am looking for. I just want to rollback to last successful deployment if any release stage gets failed at any point.

Comment: It worked for me. can you share your all the release pipeline and the release history?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk edited post with release history. There is one successful release before I intentionally failed stage just to see if rollback is working. No manually trigger is done for that.

Comment: When you click on the successful release you have green stage with a date, which date is?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk it is 5 days older.. 11 sep

Answer (score 0):

You can view the Deployments in Release pipeline to check if the deployment is triggered as expected, like this.
[image]

Which job do you use in your stage task? Agent job or Deployment group job? As my test, when I run the task in Agent job, the Auto-redeploy trigger isn’t triggered as expected, but when I run the task in Deployment group job, it works as expected. So it may be the reason for your problem, you can check it on your side.

Comment: I check deployment/release summary, it didn't re-trigger definition on failure. To answer your second question, i am using Agent job. Are you suggesting i should use deployment group job to achieve this ?

Comment: Yes, you can try to use deployment group job and I think it will work as your expected.

Comment: ok, i will try to use deployment group. Lets hope that will work. Thanks for your time. Will let you know what happens.

Comment: Any update? Did the Auto-redeploy trigger work fine now?

Comment: it worked without using deployment group as well. I don't know how it started but suddenly it seems like on failure release, deployment automatically picking and triggering last successful deployment without any additional changes. It seems like it took some time configure or i don't know exact reason. Btw thanks you for your time and suggestion.